# Get posts from multiple facebook pages with koala gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

Can I get posts from multiple pages without call "me" in @graph.get_connections?? Here my example:

Normally, I can get posts from multiple pages with this code:

```
posts = @graph.get_connections("me","?fields=posts&ids=88218378779564,1444731790495674")
```

But when i check in garph explorer, I realized that I can get posts like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/?fields=posts.limit(10)&ids=88218378779564,1444731790495674
```

without call "me" like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me?fields=posts.limit(10)&ids=88218378779564,1444731790495674
```

So, In rails app, I tried this:

```
posts = @graph.get_connections("?fields=posts&ids=88218378779564,1444731790495674")
```

but it doesn't work. Please help me to fix that or tell me another way(without call "me"!)

Comment: Hello, can you tell me where I can look the result of getting posts? How is it formatted? JSON? Which data is retrieved besides the post content?